# How to change the value length of a character using javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, newline

I am trying to change the value of a newline or carriage return to equal two as opposed to one when it is entered into a textarea. Any suggestions on how to accomplish using javascript or jQuery?

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to achieve. For a given value of `textarea.value`, what would the desired `console.log` be?

Comment: but for what its worth, you cant change the length of a string by assigning to the length property - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length#Assigning_to_length

Comment: I just need new lines and carriage returns to have a length of 2, right now they have a length of 1

Comment: string.length is a readonly property

Comment: `textarea` is undefined in this snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to `normalize` line shifts, assuming you have the string with either

one or two characters (doesn't matter), you can use this method to replace an set the value of the textarea:

var inputString = 'example\rline 2';
$('textarea').val(inputString.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, '\r\n'));

Now your textarea will contain the fixed string.